# Loadtesting ajax applications based on jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, testing, load-testing

Does anyone have any experience in load testing ajax applications? specifically running jQuery as their javascript library?

Loadrunner and Neoload is the two of the load testing applications that works on the gui layer. But none of whom supports the jquery library.

As for the other load testing tools, like jmeter, grinder and other http layer tools. they just don't cut it as you need to maintain application logic in your tests.

Selenium however uses real browsers which combined with selenium grid could be an option (also look www.browsermob.com), but then again installing a testing environment locally requires a lot of hardware.

Comment: browsermob.com is out of the question for my project, as we cannot allow for external access to our test platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I looked, both LoadRunner and NeoLoad work at the HTTP layer, not the GUI layer.  Just because a tool works at the HTTP layer does not mean that you need to replicate application logic in the tests. Smarter tools, like Load Tester (from webperformance.com), can configure many testcases automagically with little user intervention. We use it frequently with AJAX sites, though I've not looked specifically at JQuery use cases.

Comment: Yes sorry, Neoload works on the http layer, however laodrunner has a click and script protocol which works on the gui layer. but they also have a pure http protocol which is on the http layer.

Answer (score 0):

When load testing, you simulate the load on the *server*. The server is oblivious of what's happening in the client, and only cares about what HTTP requests are sent.

The main difficulty Ajax adds to load-testing is that it may involve trickier correlation scenario, so whatever tool you choose, make sure it can handle it.

I've use [RadView's WebLOAD](http://www.radview.com/) (Also HTTP based) in the past the test Ajax + jQuery app, worked like a charm.